# A Little Code Snippet Explanation

Tags: php

I am reading the code in this [page](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Generating-Session-IDs-and-Random-Passwords-with-PHP) where the author is generating random token. I understand everything except from "**line 29**" where he divides the token into chunks and hash them with md5.  My questions are::

1) Why didn't he hash the whole token but divided them and hashing them in chunks?

2) Will hashing them in chunks deliver the same results as hashing the undivided token ?

3) On "**line 36"** also he does some  **substring** which i think MAY reduce the number of characters. In doing so can the hashed token be reconstructed to the original unhashed token?

Here is the most important part of the code ::

```
# Array indice friendly number of chars; empty token string
    $numChars = count($chars) - 1; $token = '';

    # Create random token at the specified length
    for ( $i=0; $i<$len; $i++ )
        $token .= $chars[ mt_rand(0, $numChars) ];

    # Should token be run through md5?
    if ( $md5 ) {

        # Number of 32 char chunks
        $chunks = ceil( strlen($token) / 32 ); $md5token = '';

        # Run each chunk through md5
        for ( $i=1; $i<=$chunks; $i++ )
            $md5token .= md5( substr($token, $i * 32 - 32, 32) );

        # Trim the token
        $token = substr($md5token, 0, $len);

    } return $token;
}
```

I hope someone will help me get a little understanding. Thanks

**EDIT**

4) Why did he used 32 inside the substr() function?

Comment: This code is for generating random strings.  He hashed chunks, instead of the whole thing, because he felt it.  He must've felt that made it more random.

Comment: Where is line 26 and 33? Can you number your lines of code?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your great answers and replies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`md5()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is a one-way hash algorithm. Meaning it cannot be reconstructed into its original form.

To answer question 1, it creates a more secure hash. Common strings can be matched to their known hash values. This helps prevent that from happening.

2. No. Each split will give you a different result, which in this case to make it more secure, is intended.

And your edit for number 4, the third parameter (32) sets the length of the returned string. I suggest you look through the PHP manual. It's a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

1. the code (may) need to generate a token more than 32 characters long.
2. no
3. no
4. because md5() returns a 32 character string, and he needs to build up the required token length 32 characters at a time.